# how to get input field value on button click in Vuejs or in vanila javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, laravel-blade, cart

Could you please tell me how to get input field value on the button click. I want to get **input tag** value on button click which is Button Tag separated.

Here is my code below:

```
<div class="details-filter-row details-row-size">
    <label for="Qty">Qty:</label>
    <div class="product-details-quantity">
        <input type="number" id="Qty" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" data-decimals="0" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product-details-action">
    <button value="{{$ProductById->id}}" @click="addTo_Cart($event)" class="btn-cart btn-product" style="font-size: 1.3rem;" title="Add to cart">add to cart</button>
</div>
```

**And my Script below:**

```
<script>
export default{
  data: function () {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTo_Cart(e) {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
    },
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: In plain JS you can read it like - `document.getElementById('Qty').value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preferred Approach

For using Vuejs built-in tools, you can simply assign a [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) to your input element then access its value via that `v-model`.

```html
<div class="details-filter-row details-row-size">
  <label for="Qty">Qty:</label>
  <div class="product-details-quantity">
    <input type="number" v-model="inputValue" id="Qty" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" data-decimals="0" required />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-details-action">
  <button value="{{$ProductById->id}}" @click="addTo_Cart($event)" class="btn-cart btn-product" style="font-size: 1.3rem;" title="Add to cart">add to cart</button>
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        inputValue: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addTo_Cart(e) {
        console.log(this.inputValue);
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

### Other Possible Approaches

But in any case, if you don't want to use the above approach you can simply get the input value with either [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) *(Another Vuejs built-in tool)* which is provide the element in virtual DOM or [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) which is not recommended because it will use actual DOM.

- Using `ref`

```html
<div class="details-filter-row details-row-size">
  <label for="Qty">Qty:</label>
  <div class="product-details-quantity">
    <input type="number" ref="inputValue" id="Qty" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" data-decimals="0" required />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-details-action">
  <button value="{{$ProductById->id}}" @click="addTo_Cart($event)" class="btn-cart btn-product" style="font-size: 1.3rem;" title="Add to cart">add to cart</button>
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addTo_Cart(e) {
        console.log(this.$refs.inputValue);
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

- Using `getElementById`

```html
<div class="details-filter-row details-row-size">
  <label for="Qty">Qty:</label>
  <div class="product-details-quantity">
    <input type="number" id="Qty" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" data-decimals="0" required />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-details-action">
  <button value="{{$ProductById->id}}" @click="addTo_Cart($event)" class="btn-cart btn-product" style="font-size: 1.3rem;" title="Add to cart">add to cart</button>
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addTo_Cart(e) {
        console.log(document.getElementById('Qty').value);
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use form input binding as follows:

```
<div class="details-filter-row details-row-size">
    <label for="Qty">Qty:</label>
    <div class="product-details-quantity">
        <input type="number" v-model="quantity" id="Qty" class="form-control" min="1" max="10" step="1" data-decimals="0" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now add the quantity property in data section of your View component.

```
<script>
export default{
  data: function () {
    return {
      quantity: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTo_Cart(e) {
      console.log(this.quantity);
    },
}
};
</script>
```

You can now access `quantity` in button click handler as `this.quantity`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the event for this. Just use v-model with your input element like this:

```
<input v-model="myNumberValue" type="number" id="Qty" class="form-control" value="1" 
      min="1" max="10" 
       step="1" data-decimals="0" required>
<script>
  export default{
   data: function () {
    return {
      myNumberValue: 1
    };
   },
   methods: {
    addTo_Cart() {
     // the input value will be accessible using this.myNumberValue
    },
   }
  };
</script>
```

now the value of the input element will be stored in the myNumberValue property each time you change the value using input.

Comment: Actually I need this below script: `addTo_Cart(e) {
this.$store.dispatch("quantityInDe", {id: Number(e.target.id), QTY: Number(this.inputValue)} );`
    },